# Setup RESTfull api in subdomain only ?

Tags: .htaccess, api, rest, subdomain

At the moment I have a www.mydomain.com running fine without any changes to htaccess.
Now I want to create a RESTfull api to allow easy interface for other devices placed in a subdomain like www.api.mydomain.com  or www.mydommain.com/api/

Can this be done only with changes in .htaccess ? And how ?

/Thanks :-)

Comment: Just found the answer myself :-)
I just created a .htaccess file in the subfolder/domain containing : 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]

Answer (score 0):

Your question can be answered in two different ways 
First determine that  you want to use subdomains like api.yourdomain.com  or subfolders like www.yourdomain.com/api

I personally choose SubFolder because of  hierarchical  tidiness , if you want to read more about them you can Google or see  [This link](http://www.techwyse.com/blog/search-engine-optimization/should-i-use-subdomains-or-subfolders-for-seo-benefit/)

After all , if you want to use subfolder , you can do this simply by editing your .htacess like this :

```
       <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
       RewriteRule (.*) index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
       </IfModule>
```

This will tell the apache to rewrite every request to the index.php file .

you can put this file in your api folder , so this will be your folders view  :

```
       site_folder
           api
             |---->.htaccess
             |---->other_files_of_api // E.g : you classes and ...

           Core // or whatever other files in your site folder 
            .
            .
            .
            .
            index.php
            .htacess // this is another htacess , wich is in the root of your site , this is not what I wrote for you , ofcourse if can use it here as well.
```

now what is an API ?

Application Programming Interface , is simply a MVC design with any language ( mine is PHP ) , that will receive a request from other part of you site , and gives back a response .

This request can come from a Android program that you are designing or a php or what ever program that you are trying to write.

For example , if you are designing in php , and you want a API , you can access your api via [CURL](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fphp.net%2Fmanual%2Fen%2Fbook.curl.php&ei=oyllVLm0GefIyAOj_IGwBw&usg=AFQjCNHgC-iCkFg5s9Dl77qCie4t94TXlw&sig2=-CmByeOOpewlC2ZlN_ZdsA&bvm=bv.79189006,d.bGQ)
There is a lot more explanation on API , if you want : d

Comment: 1+ for the simplest explanation for api

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Just learned that you can use more than one htaccess :-)